# In App billing item not available

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have Incorporated In App billing according to docs. I published the app to play store in aplha. Now that when i added the item to the playstore and it is active item. look into image
[image]

Now inside the app i am using the same `id` i mentioned in dashboard. But following error please look into image

[image]

Here is the code that i am using.

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_buy)
public void buyCourse() {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001, mPurchasedListener);
}
```

How to fix this issue? What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

change your method to **launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow()** for in app billing

```
if (mHelper != null) {
            mHelper.flagEndAsync();
            mHelper.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_WALLET,
                    mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);

        }
```

Comment: I have generate a signed apk then i imported it to device but i get the same error

Comment: Are you using same **versionCode** for apk in alpha channel  and for apk on which you are testing

Comment: why should i do that? my item is buy for once

Comment: then why are you using in app billing add your item to in app product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129201/discussion-between-sachin-narang-and-zeeshan-shabbir).